# Sed is not working in multi double quotes

Tags: sed

This is my script in gitlab CI.

```
PASSWORD=$(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 8)
echo ${PASSWORD}
sed -i -e 's|"password":.*",|"password":"${PASSWORD}"|g' .env
```

I am using random string from tr cmd. This output value should pass to DB password of the sql instance and secrets in the secret manager.

PASSWORD output is NStPVk32. This works in gcloud sql users set-password. But sed output is not working on this variable.

How can I use this variable in sed cmd?

Comment: It will be easier to answer and test the answer if you provided example input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

```
's|password:.*|'password:$PASSWORD'|g'
```

will replace `password:xxxxxxx` with `password:NStPVk32`